# How to run Azure Devops pipeline with the help service princple with just in time access using PIM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, pim

I have an Azure Devops pipeline to create VM, I created service connection using service principal with RBAC pipeline is working.

Now I need to create service connection using service principle with PIM (just in time access) with these pipeline need to run to create VM. What can I try next?

I tried using service principal with rbac.

Answer (score 0):

According to official doc [What can you manage in PIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-deployment-plan#:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20assign%20service%20principals%20as%20eligible%20to%20Microsoft%20Entra%20roles%2C%20Azure%20roles%2C%20and%20PIM%20for%20Groups%20but%20you%20can%20grant%20a%20time%20limited%20active%20assignment%20to%20all%20three.), you cannot assign service principals as eligible to Microsoft Entra roles, Azure roles, and PIM for Groups. There is already a suggestion ticket [Support PIM for service principals](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/19899aef-c625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789) in Azure AD, if you want such a feature, you can monitor it and submit a vote.

Comment: Then how can I run the azuredevops pipeline using PIM based access